# How to bulk-load an r-tree in C#?

Tags: r-tree

I am looking for C# code to construct an r-tree. I have code that builds an r-tree incrementally i.e. items are added one by one to the tree, but I guess a better r-tree could be built if all items are given all at once to the tree creation algorithm. Please let me know if anyone knows how to bulk-load an r-tree in this manner. I tried doing some search but couldn't find anything very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The most common method for low-dimensional point data is sort-tile-recursive (STR). It does exactly that: sort the data, tile it into the optimal number of slices, then recurse if necessary.

The leaf level of a STR-loaded tree with point data will have no overlap, so it is really good. Higher levels may have overlap, as STR does not take the extend of objects into account.

A proven good bulk-loading is a key component to the Priority-R-Tree, too.

And even when not bulk-loading, the *insertion strategy* makes a big difference. R-Trees built with linear splits such as Guttmans or Ang-Tan will usually be worse than those built with the R*-Tree split heuristics. In particular Ang-Tan tends to produce "sliced" pages, that are very unbalanced in their spatial extend. It is a fast split strategy and probably the simplest, but the results aren't good.

Comment: Would please provide a (reference to) step by step description? Thanks

Comment: Google for "Sort Tile Recursive". It's all over the interwebz.

Answer (score 1):

A paper by Achakeev et al.,**Sort-based Parallel Loading of R-trees** might be of some help.  And you could also find other methods in their references.